# aspose cells workbook threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'

Tags: c#, html, formatexception, aspose-cells

the content of new.html is mentioned below:

```html
<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
    <tr>
        <td align='center' style='background-color: #18B5F0' colspan = '2'><b>Order Sheet</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = '2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Order No:</b> 100</td>
        <td><b>Date: </b>7/3/2016 12:51:00 AM </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>From :</b> Company Name </td>
        <td><b>To: </b> Some Company  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border = '1'>
    <tr>
        <th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>Id</th>
        <th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>Name</th>
        <th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John Hammond</td>
        <td>United States</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Mudassar Khan</td>
        <td>India</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Suzanne Mathews</td>
        <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Robert Schidner</td>
        <td>Russia</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using Aspose Cells for .NET version 8.8.1.0 and

This is my code snippet:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook= new Workbook(@"C:\new.html");
```

threw an exception of type `System.FormatException` and the exception details are like:

> Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>   HResult: -2146233033
>   HelpLink: null
>   InnerException: null
>   Message: "Input string was not in a correct format."
>   Source: "mscorlib"
>   StackTrace: "   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)\r\n   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)\r\n   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)\r\n   at \u0003  .\u0002(Hashtable \u0002, String \u0003)\r\n   at \u0005  .\u0002(String \u0002, ArrayList \u0003)\r\n   at \u0003​ .\b()\r\n   at \u0003​ .\u0002()\r\n   at \u0005​ .\u0002(Stream \u0002)\r\n   at \u0005​ .\u0002(String \u0002)\r\n   at Aspose.Cells.Workbook.\u0002(String \u0002, LoadOptions \u0003)\r\n   at Aspose.Cells.Workbook..ctor(String file)"
>    TargetSite: {Void StringToNumber(System.String, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, NumberBuffer ByRef, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo, Boolean)}

Answer (score 0):

Please see my [reply](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/601291/748291/showthread.aspx#748291) in your thread for your reference. Kindly follow up your thread for further updates.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.